# excel 2010 vba error calling module

Tags: excel, vba

In the below `excel 2010 vba` all the text files are opened and read by the `loop` and then a `call to a module` that is in the same sheet is made.  However I am getting an `Argument not optional' error on that line (`Call CreateXLSXFiles`).  I need some expert help in fixing this as I can not figure it out.  Thank you :)

**VBA**

```
'CREATE REPORT '
MsgBox ("Please click ok to generate analysis reports, vbOKOnly")

Dim myDir As String, fn As String
myDir = "C:\Users\cmccabe\Desktop\EmArray\"
fn = Dir(myDir & "*.txt")
Do While fn <> ""
   CreateXLSXFiles myDir & fn
   fn = Dir
Loop

Call CreateXLSXFiles
```

**Module**

```
Sub CreateXLSXFiles(fn As String)
' PARSE TEXT FILE AND CREATE XLSX REPORT '
Dim txt As String, m As Object, n As Long, fp As String
Dim i As Long, x, temp, ub As Long, myList

 myList = Array("Display Name", "Medical Record", "Date of Birth", _
                "Order Date", "Gender", "Barcode", "Sample", "Build", _
                "SpikeIn", "Location", "Control Gender", "Quality")

fp = "C:\Users\cmccabe\Desktop\EmArray\"

With Worksheets(1)
    .Cells.Clear
    .Name = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetBaseName(fn)
On Error Resume Next
n = FileLen(fn)
If Err Then
    MsgBox "Something wrong with " & fn
    Exit Sub
End If
On Error GoTo 0
n = 0
txt = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(fn).ReadAll
With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    .Global = True: .MultiLine = True
    For i = 0 To UBound(myList)
        .Pattern = "^#(" & myList(i) & " = (.*))"
        If .Test(txt) Then
            n = n + 1
            Sheets(1).Cells(n, 1).Resize(, 2).Value = _
            Array(.Execute(txt)(0).submatches(0), .Execute(txt)(0).submatches(1))
        End If
    Next
    .Pattern = "^[^#\r\n](.*[\r\n]+.+)+"
    x = Split(.Execute(txt)(0), vbCrLf)
    .Pattern = "(\t| {2,})"
    temp = Split(.Replace(x(0), Chr(2)), Chr(2))
    n = n + 1
    For i = 0 To UBound(temp)
        Sheets(1).Cells(n, i + 1).Value = temp(i)
    Next
    ub = UBound(temp)
    .Pattern = "((\t| {2,})| (?=(\d|"")))"
    For i = 1 To UBound(x)
        temp = Split(.Replace(x(i), Chr(2)), Chr(2))
        n = n + 1
        Sheets(1).Cells(n, 1).Resize(, ub).Value = temp
    Next
End With
.Copy
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    With ActiveSheet
         .Columns.AutoFit
         .Range("B1:B12").ClearContents
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fp & .Name, _
                          FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False
End Sub
```

Comment: `CreateXLSXFiles` takes a string argument but `Call CreateXLSXFiles` passes no argument. What do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

The method `CreateXLSXFiles` takes a `String` as input :

```
Sub CreateXLSXFiles(fn As String)
```

However, you're calling it without passing any string:

```
Call CreateXLSXFiles
```

In order to make it work, you need to pass the needed `fn` (that I guess it means "file name") :

```
Call CreateXLSXFiles(fn)
```

or with the newest syntax,  simply:

```
CreateXLSXFiles fn
```

Comment: That is probably OP's intention -- but in this case it should be moved into the body of the loop. On the other hand -- it already *is* in the body of the loop, so it really isn't clear what, if anything, is intended here.

Comment: @JohnColeman ah right, didn't notice that. Well now that I see the code properly, I neither understand what the OP means. Let's wait for some clarifications.

Comment: I am sorry, still learning `vba`. The `loop` ensures that all the text files in the directory are used.  Then the call is made.  So in stead of `Loop
Call CreateXLSXFiles (call made outside loop)` should it be `Call CreatXLSXFiles(fn) Loop (call made inside loop)`?  The intention is that all the text files are passed to the module.  Thank you :).

Comment: @Chris You *already* have a syntactically proper call to `CreateXLSXFiles` inside the loop -- so I wouldn't think that there is anything else to process. Why not just drop the offending line entirely? It seems to have no purpose.

Comment: @Chris I agree with John, that line of code which is raising the exception does nothing, you can simply drop it.